# Is the way Im passing variables to my function correct?

Tags: java, android, database, parameter-passing

Im currently trying to pass 2 stored strings from a database to my function gettraveltime in my Directionsmanager class. once everything runs it should change an activity from the current one to one that just has some text. but currently when I press the button nothing happens and in the logcat file the only thing that regards to getting map data are these 3 log entries.

> 2023-07-11 22:25:21.896 24459-24505 DynamiteModule          com.example.startuptest1             W  Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
> 2023-07-11 22:25:21.995 24459-24505 DynamiteModule          com.example.startuptest1             I  Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
> 2023-07-11 22:25:21.998 24459-24505 ProviderInstaller       com.example.startuptest1             W  Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

```
confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText("button pressed");
                Directionsmanager dm = new Directionsmanager();
                dm.getTravelTime(startLocation, endLocation, dbdisplay.this);
            }
        });
```

This is how Im passing the variables to my function to get the travel time between the 2 saved locations.This is the Directionsmanager class in case you need to take a look at it.

```
package com.example.startuptest1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions;
import com.google.firebase.functions.HttpsCallableResult;

public class Directionsmanager {

    private FirebaseFunctions mFunctions;
    public Directionsmanager() {
        mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
    }
    public void getTravelTime(String startLocation, String endLocation, final OnTravelTimeListener listener) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);


        if (dayOfWeek >= Calendar.MONDAY && dayOfWeek <= Calendar.FRIDAY) {

            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("startLocation", startLocation);
            data.put("endLocation", endLocation);
            data.put("mode", "transit");


            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


            if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            }


            data.put("arriveByTime", calendar.getTimeInMillis());


            mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("getTravelTime")
                    .call(data)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(HttpsCallableResult httpsCallableResult) {
                            // Handle the result
                            String travelTime = (String) httpsCallableResult.getData();
                            listener.onTravelTimeReceived(travelTime);
                        }
                    });
        } else {

            listener.onTravelTimeReceived("No action on weekends");

        }
    }

    public interface OnTravelTimeListener {
        void onTravelTimeReceived(String travelTime);
    }
}
```

I expected once I press the confirm button, it will pass the database values to Directions manager and once that runs and its returns a value it will change to a different activity. Currently  At first I thought that maybe the gridle file was incorrect in regards to versions and version compatibility but it was fine. if you need to see the function thats responsible for changing activity pls let me know. Theres a bit more code before the activity can change but Im not sure if its this part of the code or the function that is responsible for changing activity is the issue.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the call to `getTravelTime` in the callback and see if the text appears on the screen. If so, apparently, your code in `getTravelTime` is running on UI which is a cpu-intenstive task and should run in a separate thread which is different from UI thread.

You can try to use [AsyncTasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). Once you override callbacks, it will make sure to run your cpu-intensive code in a separate thread and once it is done to make changes in UI. I haven't caught up with last changes in Android but seems like AsyncTasks are deprecated, so you can use java Executors directly.

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry if I misunderstand something. currently my ``getTravelTime`` with in ``Directionsmanager`` is being called in a separate class with no UI element. again sorry this is my first android app project and Im learning as I go.

Comment: Even if you are using a separate class, the code still runs in the same thread. I recommend to familiarize yourself with the concept of threads and then try to use AsyncTasks